# Удаленный доступ на Linux

Tags: windows, linux

На работе в локалке стоит машинка с OpenSuse. Дома windows 7, но могу сменить на линукс. Хочу работать с ведром на работе (не через консоль) по RDP - подобному протоколу. Устанавливать, что либо на шлюзе нельзя, я так понимаю VPN отпадает. Поправьте если не так. Какие собственно есть программные решения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте www.teamviewer.com

Answer (score 0):

Если в на работе есть VPN и смотрит в мир, то из дома цепляешься к нему и все (у меня так сделано).

Comment: Его нет, может будет позже.

Answer (score 0):

Либо стороннее ПО, напирмер teamviewer, либо [xrdp](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNtPvcl8zVAhVBxxQKHXJiDCkQFghIMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopen-suse.ru%2Fcontent%2Fopensuse-122-i-xrdp&usg=AFQjCNEyLr3oziy3FKFpz8lqjRI0YrpcAA)